# AUTO_INCREMENT Indexing Duplicate Entry

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, import

I am attempting to load data from a csv file into a MySQL database using the LOAD DATA command.

**My csv is structured like:**

| Index | Name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | blah |  |
| 1 | blahbla |  |
| ... |  |  |

But when trying to read my data using

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    KernelName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ...,
    primary key (id)
);
USE myDatabase;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/filepath/myFile.csv'
INTO TABLE myTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I receive the error `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'myTable.PRIMARY'`

I suspect this is happening because the **AUTO_INCREMENT** is creating a MySQL table where the id starts at 1 instead of the 0 that I'm reading. Causing the duplicate entry error.

New to MySQL and don't care if indexing starts at 0 or 1, just not sure what the easiest fix would be. Should I skip the index row? Change auto_increment to start at 0?

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` is irrelevant if the data you're loading has explicit values for the `id` column. It uses whatever is in the file.

Comment: You're getting the error because the table already has `id=1`, and you're trying to load another one from the file.

Comment: @Barmar so I don't even need an `AUTO_INCREMENT` since I've already created a valid `primary key` column in my csv?

Comment: You'll need it for records you create in the future.

Comment: @fuzynutz22 you can modify the column after loading the data to include the AUTO_INCREMENT --> 
`ALTER TABLE table MODIFY id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Comment: But if there is a duplicate in `id` in the data being loaded, then it is not the primary key.  Your intention is unclear.  Perhaps you should just skip loading `id` and let the database assign an auto-incremented value to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

I was able to fix this issue by omitting the `AUTO_INCREMENT` in my initial CREATE TABLE command. Then after importing data, I used `ALTER TABLE table MODIFY id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;` to restore auto increment functionality.

Thanks to everyone who helped with this in the comments!